# es6 computed key in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

what's wrong with my code below? I want to setState using dynamic variable.

```
function(key) {
    this.setState({
       order[key]: `${this.state.order[key]}` === true ? 'asc' : 'desc'
    })
}
```

If the kye is name I expect I have `this.state.ordername`

Comment: A string (from an interpolated literal or else) will never be `=== true`.

Comment: What do you expect with `${this.state.order[key]}` === true ? 'asc' : 'desc' ?

Comment: As Bergi says, now that I'm looking more closely, there are multiple issues with this code, not just syntax.

Comment: Can you show us what you want the code to do without a computed property key? Preferably using a bracket syntax property assignment and an `if`/`else` statement. Or by including some example argument values.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following  way

```
   function(key) {
        let value = this.state.order[key] == true ? 'asc' : 'desc'
        this.setState({
           [order[key]]: value
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting state you can't directly modify object or array internal values. [Please read more here](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/102)

So you must do something like below

```
function(key) {
    let order = this.state.order;
    order[key] = (this.state.order[key] === true) ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    this.setState({order});
}
```

Thanks